# Restarting httpd on AWS EC2 behaves erratically. Is it supposed to delete the contents of /var/www/html?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Much as the title says, I'm hosting a PHP application in an EC2 instance (elastic beanstalk) on Amazon Web Services, actually running Wordpress connecting to an RDS instance. I've been needing to restart apache for a number of reasons, mainly because I'm using the mod_pagespeed apache module.

Almost without fail when I do that though, it deletes the contents of `/var/www/html/` using this command:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

I'm at a bit of a loss since I'm new to AWS, but this clearly isn't desired functionality. Is there another way I ought to go about restarting apache? Can anyone explain why that's happening?

Any advice welcomed, I feel I've got to grips well with most of the admin but this is just a head scratcher for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening with the deleting of the content, but you can try to use the graceful command to restart instead.

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

This will gracefully reload its configuration!

or the reload command

```
sudo service httpd reload
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll transfer my backup back over to the directory, get things set up and then give this a shot. If it seems to work I'll let you know!

Comment: Okay, so actually neither of those commands work. First one `apache2ctl: command not found` and the second `Equivalent Upstart operations: start httpd, stop httpd, restart httpd, status httpd
Usage:  {start|stop|restart|status|graceful}`, any further tips?

Comment: How about `sudo service httpd graceful`?

Comment: Also what Distro are you running on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Do you also have apache2 configured to start automatically on boot?you can do this with `chkconfig httpd on`

Comment: This one was actually "Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.2 (HVM)", it had some critical errors just now when I tried to rebuild the environment, so I'm going to create a fresh instance. Is there a distro you'd recommend given the details I provided of the project? Ubuntu seems like a good option actually.

Comment: Personally I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have multiple Wordpress installations with mysql. I haven't had any issues so would recommend it :)

Comment: Excellent, I'm going to get it up and running now and see how things bode :)

Comment: There is also a wordpress plugin called updraft plus https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/ you can automatically backup your installation and database to an s3 bucket, I find it really useful!

Comment: Awesome, I'll check that out. One other thing now, with this new setup only the homepage is functional, usually when I've experienced this it's just a permalink/htaccess issue, but I don't believe it is this time. Any ideas with apache config or something that I may need to edit?

Comment: Have you checked the .htaccess file yourself? You need to set permissions for the wordpress user to access the files by using `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/WordPress/Installation`. Have you set up the config virtual hosts for your installation?

I used for the .htaccess

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`

Comment: No problem dude, I fixed it, the fix actually did involve Apache config, off the top of my head I think the file was called 000-default.conf and was stored inside apache2->sites_enabled. Thanks for your help, although nothing directly solved what I was trying to do your advice helped clarify the situation for me a lot!